# How to count words for each different length in python?

Tags: python

I have to count words for a text file.

There may have strings that carry `-`, or started with a `-`. e.g. `good-morning`, but `-` will not be counted.

```
filename = input("Please input a file: ")     
openfile = codecs.open(filename,'r',encoding='utf8')
```

I only know `len()` for counting words, what kind of commant should I use to count different word length and exclude `-`?

```
str=[]
for line in filename.readlines():
print('Word length')
str.append(filename)
len(str)
print(len)
```

will i get the correct counting?

Comment: For some reason, that output image makes me think of the sample output from a homework assignment. Is this your homework?

Comment: Please, show us your code and precise where exactly problem occurs. Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service.

Comment: After splitting the words user regular expression to remove all non-alphabet characters then count the length.

Comment: may be i ask in this way  
i want some hints only, not full code

Comment: After looking at your code I can only recommend to read a Python tutorial of your choice. It's not even possible to figure out what your code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out... you can understand this too implement in your code..

```
import re
randomText ="Enter your text"
randomText = randomText.replace('\n','')
wordFrequency = {}
randomText = randomText.split(' ')
for word in randomText:
    word = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', word)
    currentWordLength = len(word)
    if(word):
        if  currentWordLength not in wordFrequency.keys():

            wordFrequency[currentWordLength]=1
        else:
            wordFrequency[currentWordLength]=      wordFrequency[currentWordLength]+1
for key in wordFrequency.keys():
    print("{0} --> {1}".format(key,wordFrequency[key]))
```

Comment: if(word):  
        if  currentWordLength not in wordFrequency.keys():  
what is .keys for?

Answer (score 0):

As you ask for hints, you have to use a `dict` to keep track of the lengths. You can feed a dict with its `setdefault` method, that adds a new key if it doesn't exist:

```
d = {}

for word in words:
    d.setdefault(len(word), 0)  # Create the key if it doesn't exist
                                # And set it to 0
    d[len(word)] += 1  # Add one word
```

You will end up with a dict with the word lengths in the keys and the count as values, e.g.

```
{1: 123, 2: 232, 3: 175 ... }
```

If you don't want to count the `-` you can simply remove it before the counting with:

```
clean_word = word.replace("-", "")  # Replace - with nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Insane, unreadable, lambda-version :)

```
from collections import Counter
input = 'here are some words\nblah, blah, good-morning. -the end-'
Counter(map (len, filter(lambda c: c.isalpha() or c.isspace(), input).split()))
```

Output:

```
Counter({4: 4, 3: 3, 11: 1, 5: 1})
```